# force both slugs in url to exist in datatabse

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have multiple categories and some details related to these categories through a ForeignKey.

I have for example categorie1 and detail1.

Now I can call categories in the url localhost:8000/categorie1

```
 path('<slug>', views.CategorieView.as_view(), name='categorie_name')
```

and details:  localhost:8000/categorie1/detail1

```
path('<anythinghereworks>/<slug>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail_name')
```

but as written in the first slug any URL like localhost:8000/abc/details1 will work.

How can I make the pattern specific to the 2 slugs?

```
#Model

class Categorie(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Detail(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name="details")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

#Views

class CategorieView(DetailView):
    model = Categorie
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = "app/categories.html"

class DetailView(DetailView):
    model = Detail
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = "app/details.html"

#URLs

path('<slug>', views.CategorieView.as_view(), name='categorie_name'),
path('<anythinghereworks>/<slug>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail_name'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename `'anythinghereworks'` to something more useful, and rename `DetailView` to avoid clashing with Django's `DetailView`. For example:

```
path('<cat_slug>/<slug>', views.MyDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_name')
```

Then you can override `get_object` to filter on `slug` and `cat_slug`.

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self):
        return Detail.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'], categorie__slug='self.kwargs['cat_slug'])
```

Or you can override `get_queryset` and filter the categorie there. You don't need to filter `slug=self.kwargs['slug']` here because Django will take care of it in the `get_object` method.

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(categorie__slug=self.kwargs['cat_slug'])
        return queryset
```

You can remove `slug_field = 'slug'` in both cases, because `'slug'` is the default value. In the first case, Django will use your `get_object` method so won't use `slug_field` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You use the [**`slug:`** *path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.CategorieView.as_view(), name='categorie_name'),
path(
    '<slug:anythinghereworks>/<slug:slug>',
    views.DetailDetailView.as_view(),
    name='detail_name'
),
```

A path converter encapsulates a regex that specifies acceptable patterns (for example the `int:` path converter will match only a sequence of digits), as well as a conversion between the substring in the URL and an object. This can be a string, for example in case of a `slug`, but the `int:` path converter for example, targets an `int`.

In your `View`s, you can then override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class DetailDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Detail
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name = "app/details.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DetailView, self).get_queryset().filter(
            category__slug=self.request.kwargs['anythinghereworks']
        )
```

to filter the queryset properly. For a request with an invalid `slug` or `anythinghereworks`, this will raise a 404.

It is also (strongly) advisable *not* to name anything `DetailView`, since it will *overwrite* the reference in your module to the new constructed class, and thus other views later in the file, will inherit from *your* `DetailView`.

I advise however to look for a better nomenclature than `anythinghereworks`. You can for example rename the parameters to `category_slug` and `detail_slug`. This will avoid a lot of confusion and thus (potential) mistakes.

Comment: thx but my question is more how should I write my detailView so that only categories that really exists will give a response. because now I can still write anything as slug:anythinghereworks in path('<slug:anythinghereworks>/<slug:slug>' that will give an answer.

Comment: @Alasdair: I know, but personally I find this "bad design" :) A lot of Python packages have such "magical names", and like the saying goes: "In a good programming languages, there are only three constants 0, 1, and infinity", it holds to some extent to strings as well. Furthermore the name of the view `DetailView`, or well actually the `SIngleObjectMixin` does not hint that it applies certain filters, which is not very "elegant" imho.